# Visual Basic in Excel - WorksheetFunction.max

Tags: vba, excel

What is the behavior of this function to be when the values being compared are equal?
If

```
Cell1 = 10
Cell2 = 11

Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.max(Cell1,Cell2)
```

Will return Cell2. But if

```
Cell1 = 10
Cell2 = 10
```

It returns Cell1.

What am I missing here?

UPDATE:

I have a label at Offset(0,-3)
If one value is greater then I get the appropriate label.
When the values are equal I get on label in particular.
Since I have not defined a consequence when the vales are equal, I wonder what I am missing
about the behavior of this function such that it will choose one value over the other when they are equal.
How much more coding should I assume is necessary?

```
Function testWinner(rng As Range) As String
  testWinner = WorksheetFunction.Index(rng, WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.max(rng), rng, 0)).Offset(0, -3)
End Function
```

[image: Result when one value is larger]
[image: Result when values are equal]

Comment: How do you determine that it is returning `Cell1` when the value is the same for both and Max simply returns 10? If the values are equal `Max` will simply return the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your updated example the following happens in your `testWinner` function:

1. The Max *value* is determined: in example one this is `15` (in example 2 it's `14`). Note that only the value but not a reference to any cell is returned
2. The MATCH function searches through through D2:D3 for the value 15 (14). It does so top down and return the first exact match. I.e. in the first example, this results in `1` (in the second example the result is `2`)
3. INDEX will return the `2`nd  element of D2:D3 (the `1`st in the second example), i.e. cell D2 (D3 in ex. 2)
4. OFFSET returns the cell three to the left

Thus, the answer to your question is not the return of the MAX function - but the MATCH function - which goes top to bottom until it finds the first element matching your criteria, in your case the max.

Independent of this: why do you use a User-Defined-Function for this? If you'd build this with the normal Excel functions, performance would be higher - and non-VBA users could still understand it. Using `=INDEX($A$2:$A$3,MATCH(MAX($D$2:$D$3),$D$2:$D$3,0))` you would save the OFFSET - and make it less error prone, as you can now insert columns between A and D without breaking your model!

Comment: Good questio. I used a UDF, because I'm a VB novice and in my google search that was the best answer I could find.

Also, the range selection is variable, so I needed input flexibility.

Your explanation was helpful. As was Maciej Los.
However, your response was most helpful.

Comment: Better use the Excel formulas without the UDF! Regarding the range: you could simply refer to the whole column (`$D:$D`), use [dynamic named ranges](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/DynamicRanges.htm) - or even better: make your data an Excel table (Insert->Table) and the ranges are adjusted automatically when you build your formula afterwards/add data!

Comment: Why do you advocate that position?
It's not just about getting the answer, I also want to improve my skill at VBA programming. 
Also, the shape of my data may not lend itself to your approach, unless that is a very general answer to the problem of comparing two values and returning information based on the one selected.
Not sure what deisgn pattern that is...

Comment: Main reason: UDFs are significantly slower than the native Excel functions (interpreted VBA vs. compiled C++). Don't know about the shape of your data, but I found that using tables and INDEX/MATCH prevents a lot of errors (e.g. changing range lengths, modified column structure) in many cases, so I'm using this approach really often. Also, using OFFSET in a UDF can cause a lot of trouble, as it messes with Excels internal calculation tree and you can end up in circular references or Excel "thinking" there is a (non-existing) circular reference

Comment: Ok. I'll take that into consideration when the sheets get really big.
For this solution, speed is not an issue.
I think this would be really important with actuarial analysis though.

Comment: Independent of speed, I try to use native Excel where I can - makes Excel tool easier to understand for other users, has less hidden assumptions (e.g. the -3 in your VBA) and works even if opened from mail, as no VBA included :-)

Comment: That's great. As I wrote, I am learning to use VBA, so your approach is cool and all, but your reasons sound like pure preference, they don't convince me not to use UDF's. It sounds like you are saying UDF's are NEVER to be used. Which I haven't read anything so far that convincingly points out why I should adopt that perspective. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Just so you don't get the wrong idea: I'm also using UDFs - though I try to avoid them where I can for the above reasons! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with `Max` (now that you've edited your question). `Max` simply returns the value (since they are all the same) and your `Match` function is looking for an **exact match** so it scans through the range until it finds the first match then that position is passed to Index.

Answer (score 1):

[WorksheetFunction.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840751%28v=office.15%29.aspx) does not return a cell/range. It returns  the largest value in a set of value.

By the way: in case of when both values are equal (10,10), the result of **Min**, **Max** and **Average** function will be the same: **10**.

If by saying the behaviour of function you mean how it works, it sorts data and gets the highest value. So, in case of set of value: {**10, 10, 8**}

```
Max(10,10,8)** = 10
Max.K({10,10,8},2) = 10 'where K = 2, which means the second highest value
Max.K({10,10,8},3) = 8  'where K = 3, which means the third highest value
```

On the other hand...

```
 row/column     A    B

    1           10   =RANK(A$1:A$3,A1) 'returns 1
    2           10   =RANK(A$1:A$3,A2) 'returns 1
    3           8    =RANK(A$1:A$3,A3) 'returns 3
```

Is it more understandable, now?

Comment: I know that. That wasn't the question.

Comment: @KenIngram, i answered your question. Function returns the largest value. In a second case, both values are equal, so it must return 10. That's all.

Comment: In case when two values are equal, the result of  Max(10,10), Min(10,10) and Average(10,10)  will be the same: 10.

Comment: You answered something that I didn't ask. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: Ha, ha, ha... :laugh: You totally changed your question! Do not expect that i can read in your mind. I'll try to answer updated question.

Comment: "If by saying the behaviour of function you mean how it works, it sorts data and gets the highest value. So, in case of set of value: {10, 10, 8}"

That's what I was wondering.

Comment: I'd check this as answered if you kept it to the sentence referencing behavior, which is what I asked about.

As well, the question is about {10,10,10,10}, in which case, the sorting behavior would give the first value in the array.

Thanks for your time.